# Blender 4.0 bring back underlined letters

Tags: interface

I just installed Blender 4.0 and usually I in nearly every menu,
the underlining of letters disappeared. And with it, the accesibilty through keys.

Is there a way to activate those letters again?

[image: Letters]

(that screen is from Blender 3.6)